# How to set color in empty UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to replicate Gowalla UI of the detail part (the table with Map & Directions) picture below
[image]

I replicate it with a table with a contentInset, set backgroundColor to clearColor, and change color of UITableViewCell in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to white, but the result 
isn't what I expected the empty cells are white only the cells with content (a number return by `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` ) here is a result I got

[image]

Is there any way to set empty cell color or any guide on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to no response for long time I would posted my solution here. I solved this problem by having UITableView under UIView and set parent view background color the same as UITableViewCell color.

Answer (score 0):

Set background color of view same as you are setting for your cell. and make cell transparent.

Comment: If I set UITableView backgroundColor to white the content behind the table (In Gowalla case, the number of people and check-in) would be unseen.